# How to play DRM content with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to play a DRM content using `react-native-video`. Is there an option to play DRM content? How do I do it? I am also open to using the `ExoPlayer` version of `react-native-video`. If `react-native-video` cannot play DRM, what other options are there?

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: @FábioSalata You replace `react-native-video`'s implementation of ExoPlayer with yours which supports DRM.

Comment: anyluck @khateeb. Searching for the same.

Comment: any luck @khateeb looking for a solution